# JPA does not ignore custom function

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Im using:
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa v2.5.12.
spring-boot: v2.5.12

I have the following repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "flow", path = "flow")
public interface FlowRepository extends
    PagingAndSortingRepository<Flow, String>,
    NativeSqlRepository
```

In the NativeSqlRepository, I have a custom function.

```
public interface NativeSqlRepository {
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> querySelect(String query, Object... parameters);
}
```

and an implementation for this function in *NativeSqlRepositoryImpl*
I don't want Spring Data JPA to generate queries based on the function name.

I'm getting the follow error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: 
Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.ge.predix.cyber.util.database.NativeSqlRepository.querySelect(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[])! 
Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.ge.predix.cyber.util.database.NativeSqlRepository.querySelect(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[])! 
No property querySelect found for type Flow!;
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.ge.predix.cyber.util.database.NativeSqlRepository.querySelect(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[])! 
No property querySelect found for type Flow!
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the code was fine.
The problem was the the repository is found on a different class path.
So, I needed to specify it in the JPA repositories.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.cyber.util.database","com.message.tracing.repository"})
public class Application {...}
```